# Adding scroll bar at start, not after first touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, scrollbar

I'm displaying an `webView`, and only after touching it and scrolling down the page the `scroll bar` appears.

How can I automatically at start,when displaying the `webView` set the the `scroll bar` so it be shown, and is it possible to control his color in `objective c` and not in `HTML` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying the indicator, you can use the following trick:

1. Implement `webViewDidFinishLoad` and use this method `flashScrollIndicators`:

   ```
   -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
       [webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
   }
   ```
2. Use this category to display the indicator:

   ```
   #define noDisableVerticalScrollTag 836913

   @implementation UIImageView (ForScrollView)

   - (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha {

   if (self.superview.tag == noDisableVerticalScrollTag) {
       if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin) {
           if (self.frame.size.width < 10 && self.frame.size.height > self.frame.size.width) {
               UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
               if (sc.frame.size.height < sc.contentSize.height) {
                   return;
               }
           }
       }

       if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin) {
           if (self.frame.size.height < 10 && self.frame.size.height < self.frame.size.width) {
               UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
               if (sc.frame.size.width < sc.contentSize.width) {
                   return;
               }
           }
       }
   }

   [super setAlpha:alpha];
   }
   @end
   ```
3. Then, give your `UIWebView` the tag like this:

   ```
   [webViews.scrollView setTag:noDisableVerticalScrollTag];
   ```

That's it, the indicator will keep in the screen after the page finish loading.

for the color issue, Do you mean to change the indicator color?

Comment: Thanks,now after first touch it's really stays visible, but at the beginning it's invisible...can I show it at start also? I used  `[self.webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];` in `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

Comment: it's working at the start, but after the page finish loading, try it.

Comment: The page finish loading (small page) and only after a 'small' touch it displayed.I saw that when i changing `webView` with tabs without scrolling nothing happens,but after any scroll on one page the `scroll bar` displayed and all other pages are shown with scroll bar.

Comment: weird, I've test it on the simulator and on actual device, it's work perfectly, without touching the `UIWebView` the indicator appear, anyway, if you find my answer useful and helped you, don't forget to accept it and up-vote my answer.

Comment: Its works!! but when changing `webView` by tabs the scroll bar size passing also and only after touching re-sizing, do you now how to re-size it or display it at top on each `webView`?